# PhoneGap Android from 3.7.0 to 4.0.2 cross-domain XHR 404's

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, phonegap-build

I have an Android application with the following in `config.xml`:

```
<access origin="*" />
```

Then, I begin a request to an API end-point using Angular `$http` like this:

```
$http({
  data: this._createTokenRequest(tenant, username, password),
  method: 'POST',
  headers: { Accept: 'application/json', 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
  timeout: 10000,
  url: url + '/api/RequestToken'
}).catch(err => {
  alert(err.message || err);
  alert(JSON.stringify(err));
}).then(response => {
  alert(response);
});
```

In `3.7.0` the response handler will be invoked. Since upgrading to `4.0.2` (using PhoneGap Build setting `<preference name="phonegap-version" value="cli-5.1.1" />` as according to http://phonegap.com/blog/2015/06/16/phonegap-updated-on-build/), the `catch` is invoked with a `404 Not Found` error.

What could have caused this? I see no relevant entry in the changelog (https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/blob/4.0.2/RELEASENOTES.md).

Comment: Any other messages spat out with the 404? Also, they have completely changed their whitelisting, you need to add the `cordova-plugin-whitelist` plugin.

Comment: No additional messages. The plugin `cordova-plugin-whitelist` looks promising, but alas, PhoneGap build does not have it. Raised a question about this at http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/cross-domain-xhr-with-cordova-plugin-whitelist-on-pgb?rfm=1. Now we wait and see again..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you switch to `cli-5.1.1`, you will switch to the `4.0.x` version of Android. As @laughingpine has pointed out in a comment, the white-listing mechanism has been changed. Earlier, you could use `<access origin="*" />` to obtain access to all domains. This no longer applies.

Now you need `cordova-plugin-whitelist` (https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist). Please refer to the documentation for the specifics. The rough equivalent of the earlier wildcard is `<allow-navigation href="*" />`, which is the new mechanism.

To build under PhoneGap Build (hence forth referred to as PGB), you will need to add the plugin. Since the plugin is available under `npm` (the Node Package Manager), you can find the latest version under the `cordova-plugin-whitelist` name (https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-whitelist). PGB can build a plugin from `npm` with the following notation:

```
<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" version="1.0.0" source="npm" />
```

Now PGB will build correctly and your whitelist works as before.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else who had a legacy app built in phonegap but updated their build process to use a recent version of cordova, Roel's answer needs a slight tweak.

old `config.xml`

```
<widget ... />
     <name>Legacy App built in phonegap</name>
     <access origin="*" />
</widget>
```

new `config.xml` for cordova

```
<widget ... />
     <name>Legacy App built in phonegap</name>
     <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" version="1" />
     <allow-navigation href="*" />
</widget>
```

If you get an `XML: unbound prefix` exception being thrown, this may help.