# Error in Accessing exrenal database file using ajax call in Phonegap app

Tags: jquery, ajax, cordova, phonegap-build

I am developing Phonegap app in which I am accessing a database hosted on another server with ajax calls. its working fine in local, but when I make APK and run that app it generates 404 Error.

**Error:**

POST http://mywebsite.com/mobileapp/function.php 404 (Not Found)**

**App html File:**

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />
    <!-- WARNING: for iOS 7, remove the width=device-width and height=device-height attributes. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-4323 -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">
    <script src="js/jquery-2.2.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
<p><span id="usermessage" style="color: red; font-weight: bold;"></span></p>
        <div id="formdiv">
            <form action="#" method="post" >
                <p> <input type="text" name="username" id="username" placeholder="Enter Usernam" ></p>

                <p> <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Enter Password"></p>
                <p> <input type="button" id="submit" value="Login" class="button" ></p>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function ()
        {
            $("#submit").click(function () {
                $("#submit").css("background-color", "red");
                var un = $("#username").val();
                var pass = $("#password").val();
                var status = "login";
                if (un == '' || pass == '')
                {
                    $("#usermessage").text("Please Enter Username and Password");
                }
                else {
                    $("#usermessage").text("Else");

                    $.ajax({
                            type: 'POST',
                            dataType: 'json',
                            data: "username="+un+"&password="+pass+"&status="+status,
                            url: 'http://mywebsite.com/mobileapp/function.php',
                            crossDomain: true,
                            cache: false,
                            success: function(data){
                             console.log(data.ID);
                             $("#submit").css("background-color", "green");
                             $("#usermessage").text("Login Successful");
                            },
                            error: function(data){
                                    console.log(data);
                             $("#submit").css("background-color", "black");
                            }
                    });
                }
            });

        });
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        app.initialize();
    </script>
</body>
```

**App config.xml file**

```
<widget xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0" id="com.phonegap.helloworld" version="1.0.0">
<name>mywebsite</name>
<description>testetstesetst</description>
<author href="http://mywebsite.com" email="support@mywebsite.com">mywebsite Team</author>
<content src="index.html"/>
<preference name="permissions" value="none"/>
<preference name="orientation" value="default"/>
<preference name="target-device" value="universal"/>
<preference name="fullscreen" value="true"/>
<preference name="webviewbounce" value="true"/>
<preference name="prerendered-icon" value="true"/>
<preference name="stay-in-webview" value="false"/>
<preference name="ios-statusbarstyle" value="black-opaque"/>
<preference name="detect-data-types" value="true"/>
<preference name="exit-on-suspend" value="false"/>
<preference name="show-splash-screen-spinner" value="true"/>
<preference name="auto-hide-splash-screen" value="true"/>
<preference name="disable-cursor" value="false"/>
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="14"/>
<preference name="android-installLocation" value="auto"/>
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.media-capture"/>
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.console"/>
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device"/>
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device-motion"/>
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device-orientation"/>
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.dialogs"/>
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file"/>
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file-transfer"/>
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.geolocation"/>
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.globalization"/>
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser"/>
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.media"/>
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.network-information"/>
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.splashscreen"/>
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.vibration"/>
<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" version="1.0.0" source="npm" />
<icon src="icon.png"/>
<icon src="www/res/icon/android/icon-36-ldpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="ldpi"/>
<icon src="www/res/icon/android/icon-48-mdpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="mdpi"/>
<icon src="www/res/icon/android/icon-72-hdpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="hdpi"/>
<icon src="www/res/icon/android/icon-96-xhdpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="xhdpi"/>
<icon src="www/res/icon/blackberry/icon-80.png" gap:platform="blackberry"/>
<icon src="www/res/icon/blackberry/icon-80.png" gap:platform="blackberry" gap:state="hover"/>
<icon src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-57.png" gap:platform="ios" width="57" height="57"/>
<icon src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-72.png" gap:platform="ios" width="72" height="72"/>
<icon src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-57-2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="114" height="114"/>
<icon src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-72-2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="144" height="144"/>
<icon src="www/res/icon/webos/icon-64.png" gap:platform="webos"/>
<icon src="www/res/icon/windows-phone/icon-48.png" gap:platform="winphone"/>
<icon src="www/res/icon/windows-phone/icon-173-tile.png" gap:platform="winphone" gap:role="background"/>
<gap:splash src="www/res/screen/android/screen-ldpi-portrait.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-ldpi"/>
<gap:splash src="www/res/screen/android/screen-mdpi-portrait.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-mdpi"/>
<gap:splash src="www/res/screen/android/screen-hdpi-portrait.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-hdpi"/>
<gap:splash src="www/res/screen/android/screen-xhdpi-portrait.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-xhdpi"/>
<gap:splash src="www/res/screen/blackberry/screen-225.png" gap:platform="blackberry"/>
<gap:splash src="www/res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait.png" gap:platform="ios" width="320" height="480"/>
<gap:splash src="www/res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="640" height="960"/>
<gap:splash src="www/res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-568h-2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="640" height="1136"/>
<gap:splash src="www/res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-portrait.png" gap:platform="ios" width="768" height="1024"/>
<gap:splash src="www/res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-landscape.png" gap:platform="ios" width="1024" height="768"/>
<gap:splash src="www/res/screen/windows-phone/screen-portrait.jpg" gap:platform="winphone"/>
<access origin="http://mywebsite.com"/>
<allow-navigation href="http://mywebsite.com/*" />
<allow-intent href="http://mywebsite.com/*"/>
<allow-intent href="https://*/*"/>
<allow-intent href="tel:*"/>
<allow-intent href="sms:*"/>
<allow-intent href="mailto:*"/>
<allow-intent href="geo:*"/>
<platform name="android">
<allow-intent href="market:*"/>
</platform>
<platform name="ios">
<allow-intent href="itms:*"/>
<allow-intent href="itms-apps:*"/>
</platform>
</widget>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**NOTE TO ALL:** This app use an unrestricted whitelist filter - intended for development only.
**THIS APP EXAMPLE IS INSECURE. IT IS UP TO YOU TO SECURE YOUR APP.**
 In addition, your app maybe reject by Google and Apple.

---

I'm clueless, but maybe you have not the right `cordova-plugin-whitelist`

You are currently using

```
<plugin name="com.indigoway.cordova.whitelist.whitelistplugin" source="pgb" />
```

I think you need to change that

try: `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-whitelist`

or in your config.xml file :

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1" />
```

but if you are using the online phonegap build service the syntax is different. You have to add the following line in your config.xml file :

```
<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" source="npm" />
```

and authorize cross domain requests :

```
<access origin="*" />
<allow-intent href="*" />
<allow-navigation href="*" />
```

All Credits go to: 
[Phonegap Cordova Ajax requests 404 (Not Found) Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30048453/phonegap-cordova-ajax-requests-404-not-found-error)

and here: [Ajax Command to request URL no longer working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29757593/ajax-command-to-request-url-no-longer-working)

Comment: no it does not effected. its a phonegap cross platform problem, something with configuration

Comment: Then I'm clueless, I'll look into it now. Hope I can help you otherwise I hope someone else will help you soon.

Comment: Another topic regarding the subject http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13920782/phonegap-javascript-sending-cross-domain-ajax-request

Comment: i have used domain whitelist, but its not working i think i have made some mistake which i am unable to find

Comment: you can see my config and html file i have added the whitelist domain

Comment: I didn't see that, sorry. Can you see errors other than the 404?

Comment: Have you seen this one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30895374/phonegap-android-from-3-7-0-to-4-0-2-cross-domain-xhr-404s

Comment: Yes i have done the same, i just made it work , i was using old version command thats why it was creating problem.

Comment: but getting response in error not in Success. which is not supposed to be that way

Comment: Response but now in the error section? Might be that you're not passing JSON correctly. Try: 

    data: JSON.stringify(array),
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',

Comment: Thanks for the edits. I wasn't aware of the security issues as my experience with cordova is minimal.